# Why angular-xeditable doesn't highlight the current value at the first run?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, x-editable

I use angular-xeditable with dropdowns for in-place editing like that ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqrrw96q/2/)). The strange thing is that I don't see the current value highlighted as selected when I click on xeditable link right after page is loaded. Any ideas on why is this happening?

**HTML**

```html
Person: <a href="#" editable-select="user.name" 
 buttons="no"
 e-ng-options="p as personDetails.text for (p, personDetails) in people"> 
 {{people[user.name].text}} </a>
Status: <a href="#" editable-select="user.status"
 buttons="no"
 e-ng-options="s as statusDetails.text for (s, statusDetails) in statuses"> 
 {{statuses[user.status].text}}
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```js
app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    status: 2,
    name: 2
  };

    $scope.statuses = {
      '1': { text: 'status1'},
      '2':{ text: 'status2'},
      '3':{ text: 'status3'},
      '4':{ text: 'status4'}
      };
  $scope.people = {
      '1': { text: 'p1'},
      '2':{ text: 'p2'},
      '3':{ text: 'p3'},
      '4':{ text: 'p4'}
      };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fond of the names of the properties i chose, but I prefer the use of an array, the issue is solvable if you use objects:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    Person: <a href="#" 
    editable-select="user.person" 
    buttons="no" 
    e-ng-options="p.text for p in people track by p.value"> {{user.person.text}} </a>
</div>

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.people = [
       { value: '1', text: 'p1' },
       { value: '2', text: 'p2' },
       { value: '3', text: 'p3' },
       { value: '4', text: 'p4' }
    ];

    $scope.user = {person: $filter('filter')($scope.people, {value : 3})[0]};
});
```

Also it wont work with the version of AngularJS you were referencing, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dq38z6Le/) is a working fiddle.